# Why do Glitch projects not play in my Chrome browser?

Tags: aframe

I'm a newbie who was told to use Aframe instead of unreal or unity, so I went to aframe.io and found a link to glitch vr projects, but I couldn't see them until I used Firefox and Safari. I assume I have something turned off in Chrome, right? If that's the case, it makes me concerned that users may also have the same issue.
Thanks for you time reading this.

Comment: Does Your console throw any errors ( ctrl+shit+i) ? I have no issues @chrome ver.60.0.3112.113.

Answer (score 0):

Because I was on an old Mac laptop, the fix was to go to Chrome settings Advanced section and enable "Use hardware acceleration when available"